# Recuperar un sass original de un css minificado

Tags: sass

Tengo un archivo css que esta minificado con grunt. Por un error me quedo el sass original fuera del repositorio. Necesitaria sacar el sass original de ese css. 
saludos

Comment: Si no es tu primer _commit_ puedes recuperar/ver uno de un comit/release/branch anterior. Por otro lado, el CSS es SASS válido, así que puedes continuar usándolo.

Comment: Si quieres recuperar tus variables, mixin, anidado de clases, etc no es posible ya que estos no se imprimen en tu css al compilar, entonces no puedes recuperar algo que no existe. Lo único viable es que desminifiques el css lo utilices como scss o lo conviertas a sass con alguna herramienta en línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esta herramienta para convertir tu CSS a SASS/SCSS:

http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

Solo copia y pega el contenido de tu css, selecciona el formato y listo.

Comment: Eso no le devolverá su SASS original, esas herramienta lo único que hacen es anidar los selectores y poco más. Si tenía funciones, mixins, variables, etc. no los recuperará.

Comment: Si, ya lo probe. para partes de codigo sirve pero para recuperar el original lo veo dificil. gracias